# Perfect infinitive? What is the correct phrase?

Tags: infinitives, perfect-constructions

> We happened to have been late for school today.
>
> We happened to be late for school today.

What's the right way of putting it?

Answer (score 2):

*We happened to be late today* views 'this morning' as the past.

If you use the perfect tense to speak about today, you would have to say *We happen to have been late today* (the situation now is that we were late this morning).

You could say *We happened to have been late for school **that** day*, speaking of a day in the past.

Comment: Technically the "being late" can have happened in the past, even if it happened today. So I would say both are correct.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, of course being late today is in the past, but I would still use _happen_ in the present tense for an incident earlier today.